# async running in main thread

Tags: python, python-3.x

Having this async method that return a coroutine

```
async def async_task() -> str:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(threading.current_thread().name)
    return f"Hello Async world {random.randint(1, 100)}"
```

why when I await for the result

```
await async_task()
```

the print says that I'm in the main thread?

```
MainThread
```

I was expecting to see a thread name of the event loop

Comment: You are using `threading` module.....And you should know coroutine would only use one thread normally.

Comment: I just start this week learning Python, what do you mean coroutine only use one thread?. what happen when I run two coroutines in parallel, in which threads are executed?

Comment: So i mean, *normally*

Comment: Try to use `print(asyncio.current_task)`.

Comment: CPython still has GIL and so a multi-threaded application is suboptimal. AsyncIO is to effectively handle a lot of I/O operations w/o need of parallel code execution. You will have to mange creation of threads on your own.